# Microsoft Access and SQL Azure Performance Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, azure

We are trialing to use SQL Azure as our backend with Microsoft Access. However we are having a huge performance issue running simple queries in code or as a query. When the same query is run directly against the SQL Azure database from the local SQL Management Studio Query windows it executes fine.

Note: The same queries executes fine against the local SQL database.

- MSAccess 2013
- ODBC SQL Native 11.0
- DAO
- Tables are linked (not a web app)

Any body have any ideas or about performance issues.

Comment: I haven't kept up with Access for a few years, and cannot speak to 2013, but in the past Access would bring much data across the wire and do lots of processing, including the joins and the WHERE-CLAUSE filtering, on the client. The only truly bandwidth-efficient way to use Access against a server-engine was to issue pass-through queries.

Answer (score 0):

I use access as a front end for a redbrick data warehouse.  There may be some similarities in our situations.  My observation is that if the redbrick table has a multi-column primary key, the queries take a very long time.  In fact, I'm even able to see what happens.

What I see resembles this.  Let's say my redbrick table, we'll call it MyTable, has a 5 column primary key.  One of them is called TheDate.  I build a query in access that basically resembles this:

```
select somefields
from MyTable
where field1 = [prompt for value]
and TheDate > 7 days ago, whatever that syntax is in access.
```

If I submit a value that causes no records to be returned, it's instant.  However, even if there is only going to be one record returned, I see this sort of sql running in redbrick.

```
select somefields
from MyTable
where (field1 = something
and TheDate = something
and field 3 = something
and field4 = something)
or (same sort of thing for a different date)
and so on for all 7 days in the date range.
```

I don't particularly care because I am the user and I think the results are worth waiting for.  In fact, sometimes I look at StackOverflow while I'm waiting.

On the other hand, pass through queries are just like querying the database directly.  Also, queries against tables with a single key primary key are quick.

This might be what is happening to you.  Or it might be something else.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My query is a simple append from one table to another. I believe I will need to use pass through queries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are linking tables from a remote SQL Server instance on Azure and running your queries on the MS Access front-end?

If that's the case, there are lots of things that can affect performance:

- Access attempts to run the queries on the server whenever possible, but that's not always the case if you are writing your queries in a way that requires Access to pull raw table data from the server to execute the queries itself locally.
  This happens for instance if you have UDF (User-Defined Functions in VBA) in your queries or if you use functions that only Access has, and not SQL Server.
- In your queries, be careful if you mix local tables with remote tables, you'll end-up transferring a lot of data, possible the whole tables if the query cannot be optimised by MSAccess.
- If you do not have a ROWVERSION field on each of your tables in SQL Server, MSAccess will need to read a lot more data than it would need to ascertain if a particular row has been changed (if will need to read all the fields to compare them to its cache).
- If your indexes are not adapted to the type of queries you run, you can also end-up with a lot more data being pulled than necessary.

*You can try to mitigate the issues*

- Make sure your queries are not pulling more data than you really need.
  Use the profiler tools for SQL Server to find out exactly what is being executed and how much data is requested by Access.
- Use pass-through queries. They will run entirely on the server.
- Define views on SQL Server that will return the data you need, and then link these views as tables in your front-end.
- Define store procedures that can compute and return just the data you need.
- Avoid binding remote data to forms containing too many controls.

*References*

- [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)